# How to load multiple keras models into a python dictionary using threading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, dictionary, keras

I have to load 4 keras models into a python dictionary parallely to reduce loading time.
My code is as follows

```
import *
from threading import Thread
models_out = {}

def model_loading(arg,model_num):
    ###code to fetch model_object based on model_num###
    models_out.update(model_num: model_object)

def prediction():
    thread0 = Thread(target=model_loading, args=(arg, "model_one",))
    thread1 = Thread(target=model_loading, args=(arg, "model_two",))
    thread2 = Thread(target=model_loading, args=(arg, "model_three",))
    thread3 = Thread(target=model_loading, args=(arg, "model_four",))

    thread0.start()
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread3.start()
    thread0.join()
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
    thread3.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    prediction()
```

my models_out variable should be

`{"model_one":model_object,"model_two":model_object,"model_three":model_object,"model_four":model_object}`

it is causing the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(115, 10), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to change a little bit the structure of the code:

1. update the function `model_loading` to take a file path (i.e. the model checkpoint to load) and to return the model loaded (instead of updating the `model_out` variable)
2. Use the [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) built-in and create one thread per model to load

```py
import concurrent.futures as cf

def model_loading(file_path):
   ... # code to load your model
   
   return model_loaded

def prediction():
   model_file_paths = ["model_file_path1", "model_file_path2"]

   with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(model_file_paths)) as executor:
      models_loaded = executor.map(model_loading, model_file_paths)

   models_out = dict(zip(model_file_paths, models_loaded)) # mapping from file_path -> model object
   
   return models_out
```